# Use of textOutput() in a conditionalPanel

Tags: r, shiny

I have a text output (it is only a number), which I would like to use in a conditional panel. In server.R, I define the output as

```
output$mymse <- renderText({
  xvals.out()
})
```

I then tried to call it in ui.R as follows:

```
conditionalPanel("input.sliderTwo != 0",
     h5("I would like to have the textOutput below"),
     textOutput("mymse"),
     sliderInput("sliderThree", label = "Question 3", min = 0, max = 4, value = 0, step = 1)))
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to use the `textOutput` value  in the **condition** of your `conditionalPanel`? And if such, how exacly do you want that to be? E.g. only if the number "5" would appear as `textOutput`, you want the number to be shown + additional Elements?

Comment: @ K. Rohde - Thank you for the comment. I want to ask questions, which depend on calculations in the server.R file. That is, for example, I'd like to ask "would you prefer the number X", where X would be the textOutput. The question here is just made up (I know it's not very profound). Is it more clear? PS: The idea would then be that one can move a slider to reply.

Comment: So you want to integrate the `textOutput` value into the `h5` tag? Why don't you just already paste the question inside `output$mymse` and then have `h5(textOutput("mymse"))` in your UI? That would be the most shiny way.

Comment: Good idea! So you would suggest that after re-defining the output, I can simply put 5(textOutput("mymse")) within the conditionalPanel?

Comment: Exactly. If you find this not sufficient, we will find another solution.

Comment: That's very generous of you. I very much appreciate your help!